# Problems in HTA

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

So I'm trying to use ScriptGUI (from [here](http://www.thegoodideasclub.co.uk/2013/01/scriptgui-front-end-for-scripts.html)) for my `.bat` files, but it doesn't have a file selector, so I attempted to add one.

I just copied and renamed some code around and it seems to work, apart from adding another variable for the subfunction thing.

```
     ' build a file selector
        ElseIf UCase(strSplit(0)) = "FILE" Then
           strHTML = strHTML & Build_File(strLabel,id,Replace(strLabel," ",""),strSplit(2))
           ' store the batch file in the arrControls array
           arrControls(id) = "file,none"
           id = id + 1
```

>
the problem seems to be the code under here `"Click_File(" & fiId & "," & fiFilter & ")"`

```
  Function Build_File(fiLabel, fiId, fiName, fiFilter)
  ' Construct a file selector
  Dim strHTML
  strHTML = "<input class='button' type='button' name='" _
            & fiName & "' value='" & fiLabel & "' id='" & fiId _
            & "' onClick=" & chr(34) & "Click_File(" & fiId & "," & fiFilter & ")" & chr(34) _
            & " onMouseOver=" & chr(34) & fiName & ".className='button btnhov'" & chr(34) _
            & " onMouseOut=" & chr(34) & fiName & ".className='button'" & chr(34) _
            & ">"
  strHTML = strHTML & " <input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='none' name='fi" & fiName & "' id='fi" & fiId & "'/> "
  Build_File = strHTML
  End Function
```

>

```
    Sub Click_File(strId, fiFilter)
  ' open a file selector
  set objShell= CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
   myCur = objShell.CurrentDirectory
  Dim file
  file = GetFileName(myCur, fiFilter)
  arrControls(strId) = "file," & file
  document.getElementById("fi" & strId).value = file
  document.getElementById("fi" & strId).size = Len(file) + 2
  End Sub
```

It tells me I can't use parenthesis when calling a sub.

Any ideas?

EDIT: new problem,

I'm using a script from Rob van der Woude for the open file dialog (top post from [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php)) which is apparently supposed to work in hta but I get an error saying "ActiveX component can't create object: 'UserAccounts.CommonDialog'"

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message isn't wrong. You *can't* use parentheses when calling a `Sub`.

Change this line from:

```
& "' onClick=" & chr(34) & "Click_File(" & fiId & "," & fiFilter & ")" & chr(34) _
```

to:

```
& "' onClick=" & chr(34) & "Click_File " & fiId & "," & fiFilter & chr(34) _
```

and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: i think it worked! funnily enough those were already there, and work fine on all the options that were put in previously

Comment: I'm now having a problem with this line    set objShell= CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")

It says variable is undefined: objShell

Comment: Call a sub with a single arg "works". When using multiple args, however, you'll get the error mentioned. So perhaps you added an arg to this routine?

Comment: Just Dim it first. Dim objShell.

Comment: yes, i did add a new arg, i needed one for the filter,
sorry, i'm very new to VBScript

Comment: Updated OP with new problem :/

Comment: @Az- To keep things on topic, it's probably best to submit a new question for any new issues.